# UCP query timeout property on DataSource level

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, ucp

We are using hibernate3 jar and JDK 6. And for connection pool we are using UCP-11.2.0.3. Now we are facing connection pool full issue. We have already set Abandon limit. We want to implement query timeout on UCP. Is this can be handle at DataSource level to have query timeout. I can see function `datasource.setConnectionProperty(name, value)` but didn't find property for query timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties you may set for the UCP are defined in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e12265/optimize.htm)

You may set *Time-To-Live Connection Timeout* which will cap the total time the connection is borrowed from the pool.

```
 pds.setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(18000)
```

The *query timeout* can be set **on the statement level** and is valid only for this statement - [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29) - so this is not configured via the UCP.

```
 stmt.setQueryTimeout(timeout)
```

Comment: Thanks for Info. Going with `setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout`